# Populate none ref objects of a nested array

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-populate

I'm working on a project that uses:

```
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^7.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.12",
    // ...
    "typescript": "^3.7.4",
```

With mongoose/mongoDB config:

```
      uri: MONGO_DB_URI,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useCreateIndex: true,
```

I'm trying to build a **simple CRUD** for this model:

```
export const ContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    source_id: { type: String, required: true },
    firstName: { type: String, trim: true },
    lastName: { type: String, trim: true },
    phones: [
      {
        number: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
          unique: true,
          validate: {
            validator: function(value) {
              const phoneNumber = parsePhoneNumberFromString(value)
              return phoneNumber && phoneNumber.isValid()
            },
          },
        },
        type: {
          type: String,
          default: function() {
            return parsePhoneNumberFromString(this.number).getType() || "N/A"
          },
        },
        code: {
          type: Number,
          default: function() {
            return parsePhoneNumberFromString(this.number).countryCallingCode || undefined
          },
        },
        national: {
          type: Number,
          default: function() {
            return parsePhoneNumberFromString(this.number).nationalNumber || undefined
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true, lowercase: true, trim: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true },
)

ContactSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate)
```

Like every CRUD app, I'm willing to have `fildAll()` & `fildOne()` routes that return the body of a given `Contact` **with all his info including the list of its phone numbers**. So I used:

```
  // ...
  async findAll(): Promise<Contact[]> {
    return this.contactModel.find()
    // then I add
    .populate('phones')
  }

  async findBySourceId(id: string): Promise<Contact> {
    return this.contactModel.findOne({ source_id: id })
    // then I add
    .populate('phones')
  }
  // ...
```

All info are well saved in the DB and there is no missing data (neither phones) and I'm sure that it works the beginning without even adding `.poplate('x')`, but that changed somewhere and **it returns now unpopulated phone array**.

Now It returns:

```
    {
        "_id": "5ebc22072e18637d84bcf6f0",
        "firstName": "Maher",
        "lastName": "Boubakri",
        "phones": [],
        "email": "mhb@test.im",
        // ...
    }
```

But, It should return:

```
    {
        "_id": "5ebc22072e18637d84bcf6f0",
        "firstName": "Maher",
        "lastName": "Boubakri",
        "phones": [
            {
                "_id": "5ebc22072e18637d8fd948f9",
                "number": "+21622123456",
                "code": 216,
                "type": "MOBILE",
                "national": 22123456,
            }
        ],
        "email": "mhb@test.im",
        // ...
    }
```

*Note: It is clear that MongoDB generates `_id` for every phone object, but, it is not a ref Object.*

Any idea will be so helpful,

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Mohammed 's comment and answer, adding `.lean()` after updating `mongoose` fixed the problem.

```
// ...
  async findAll(): Promise<Contact[]> {
    return this.contactModel.find().lean()
  }

  async findBySourceId(id: string): Promise<Contact> {
    return this.contactModel.findOne({ source_id: id }).lean()
  }
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

[populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) is used to join two (or more) collections using the references

here you don't have any references, so you don't need it

just use `find()` without `populate`

Comment: As I said, I  just added `.populate()` when I got empty arrays! So, What do you think could be the problem?

Comment: could you post how do call these functions findAll, and findSource? also check that the phones array exists in db

Comment: phones objects exist in DB, As I said before, all data are well saved, and there is no matter on the way I'm calling the functions!

Comment: try add `.lean()` after `.find()`, `this.contactModel.find().lean()`

Comment: adding `.lean()` after updating`mongoose` fixed the problem.
Just update your answer, mention and **please** tell me more about the `.lean()` feature so I can accept it ✅.
Thank you @Mohammed.